# C# LINQ Find Difference in One to Many

Tags: c#, linq

I have a one to many dictionary and I need to find any discrepancies within the data to send to the users. Below is my query

```
var FinalQuery = from final in masterquery
                 where final.gpa_vsl != string.Empty || final.eta1_datetime.Date.CompareTo(final.eta_date.Date) != 0 ||
                 final.ata_date > DateTime.MinValue || final.cfit_vsl != final.gpa_vsl
                 group final by final.file_no into newGroup
                 orderby newGroup.Key
                 select newGroup;
var Finaldict = FinalQuery.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

foreach(var file in FinalDict) {
     if (file.Value.Count() > 1) {
     //Here I need to find out if all eta1 and all vessel match
     //below is what I am trying to do with Linq

     bool match = from f in file.Value
          where file.Value.Count(f => f.eta1_date.CompareTo(f.eta1_date)) = file.Value.Count()
           select true;

     //What I am trying to do is if all eta1 dates match return a total int to compare to the total count of values.
     }
}
```

Dictionary looks like:

```
Key - FileNo = 123 
Value - Container = 123 , eta1 = 2/20/17, ata1 = 2/20/17, vessel = boat1 
Value - Container = 456, eta1 = 2/18/17, ata1 = 2/18/17, vessel = boat2 
Value - Container = 789, eta1 = 2/20/17, ata1 = 2/20/17, vessel = boat1 
Value - Container = 987 , eta1 = 2/20/17, ata1 = 2/20/17, vessel = boat1
```

I am open to any and all suggestions. Need to find that Container 456 info does not match the others. Hope I provided enough info

Comment: could you elaborate on what constitutes a discrepancy in your example dictionary?

Comment: The goal is to have all eta1, ata1, and vessels to match. In the above the eta1 does not match the rest of the eta1. If all do not match then I need to return an exception to the user

Comment: Just notice that `orderby` followed by `.ToDictionary` destroys the order, since a dictionary does not guarantee any order when enumerated

Comment: @chrisclifton - Is it OK that container `456` doesn't match as it is on a different vessel?

Comment: Maybe you can try counting the distinct values for each field. If there are more than 1 distinct value, then there is a discrepancy.

Comment: @chrisclifton - Your code doesn't make a great deal of sense. To get it to compile I've had to introduce `public class X { public int file_no; public string gpa_vsl; public string cfit_vsl; public DateTime eta1_datetime; public DateTime eta1_date; public DateTime eta_date; public DateTime ata_date; }`, but I don't see how that lines up with the "Dictionary looks like:" data you have provided. Can you please post the correct class definition and show us what the dictionary looks like using valid C# code and a standard dictionary initializer?

Comment: @tinudu good catch on the order by. I can remove that as they files are the keys and they don't need to be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick win would be:

```
bool match = file.Value.GroupBy(f => new {f.eta1, f.ata1, f.vessel}).Take(2).Count() == 1
```

, or better:

```
var c0 = file.Value[0];
var match = file.Value.Skip(1).All(c => c.ata1 == c0.ata1 && ...);
```

Comment: I have left work for the day but will def try both of these tomorrow. Thanks for sending this over

Comment: used the quick win. Thanks for your help